# How many entries are in a node of B-Tree of a MySQL Index?

Tags: mysql, indexing, data-structures, b-tree

This [online book](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/anatomy/the-tree) describes how MySQL leverages [B-Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) for indexing data. Time complexity depends on the number of entries per node.

How many entries does MySQL hold in one node?

Comment: Roughly (16kb-about 0.5k overhead)*fillfactor/(average size of (key values + primary key)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rule of Thumb:  100.

This applies to InnoDB data BTrees and Index BTrees.  However, it can be quite far off.

One extreme:  only 1 data record in a node -- due to large row size and/or activity such as `DELETEs`.  Another case:  A table with 1 record will still occupy a full 16KB block.

Other extreme:  500 index records in a node -- due to small size of key and lack of activity that would have deleted records.

Comment: So a node has 16KB available for keys?

Comment: @magic_al - InnoDB uses 16KB blocks for data BTree nodes; ditto for index BTree nodes.