# Foreign keys vs Composite keys in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table just like this:

```
USER_RELATIONSHIP
----------------------
user_id     follows_id
1           2
1           3
2           1
3           1
```

Both user_id and follows_id are Foreign keys that point to a User table. The USER_RELATIONSHIP table is quite large and I am frequently checking to see if a user relationship exists or not (eg. user A follows user B).

Given that these Foreign keys are indexed, is SQL able to find a relationship (given a user_id and a follows_id) in O(1)?

**If not, is it more performant to condense the two fields above into an indexed Composite key that hashes a user_id and a follows_id and having the USER_RELATIONSHIP table like this?**

```
USER_RELATIONSHIP
----------------------
composite_key
298437920           
219873423           
918204329          
902348293
```

Comment: @nbk Your comment is unrelated to my question.

Comment: hashed index have some restrictions especiall they get big quite fast also see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-btree-hash.html, my points stands unique constraint

Comment: If you are concerned about the performance hit of FKs, get rid of them (but keep the associated `INDEX`).  In most cases your application "does the right thing", thereby obviating the need for FKs.  (Yeah, yeah, FKs are there to catch a rogue ad hoc DML that "does the wrong thing".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing into an index a string that is the result of a hash function does not make it a hash index.

It's still a B-tree index, and lookups take O(log n) time.

In MySQL, the common storage engines InnoDB (the default) and MyISAM do not support hash indexes. Only Memory and NDB storage engines support hash type indexes.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html:

[image]

There is no way to do an O(1) lookup in InnoDB.

There's no difference in *complexity* between using a multi-column index vs. an index on the string result of a hash function.

Comment: I thought this question sounded familiar... I answered one like it in 2011! https://stackoverflow.com/a/7681319/20860 I won't close today's question as a duplicate, because it's not unreasonable to ask the same question 9 years later, in case there are new index features in recent versions of MySQL. But in this case, the old answer would also apply to current MySQL.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Do you suggest that I leave the USER_RELATIONSHIP as is with two indexed FK's?

Comment: Yes, it will make it easier to look up sets of entries either by `user_id` or by `follows_id`. If you hash them, you will only be able to look up specific pairs, not sets.

Answer (score 0):

It is not more performant to condense the data into a single column.  I'm rather curious why you are even asking.

If you have a compound index on `(user_id, follows_id)`, then the lookup is in O(log n) time -- the log of the number of rows in the table.  That is pretty tiny for most tables.  And, if the table is so large that the index lookup time is measurable, then you need the index all-the-more.

Comment: Because hash tables perform reads at O(1) time. O(1) is always better than O(log n). If I use a uniquely hashed indexed Composite key will I not achieve O(1)? Also, is a compound index created automatically if a row contains two foreign keys like the USER_RELATIONSHIP table?

Comment: @Rage . . . Assuming the hash table fits in memory.  Plus, big-oh notation just says what happens as n --> infinity.  For small values of n -- and millions and billions can small -- the other constants can be more important.  So, it depends.  And that doesn't even take into account that the most common storage engines don't support hash indexes.

Comment: Agreed. Do you suggest leaving my USER_RELATIONSHIP table as is?

Comment: @Rage . . . If you care about the performance of looking up rows using both keys, then create a composite b-tree index or composite primary key.

Comment: What is the time complexity difference with the table as it is now with two indexed Foreign keys vs. creating an indexed composite primary key?